# IDB DB2 Database Username and Passowrd, Trial Account

Tags: db2, passwords, jupyter, websphere, userid

I am taking the edX SQL course by IBM, and they want us to connect to our free DB2 cloud from juptyerlab, the problem is, in the DB2 Connections tab, my username is just showing as "user name" when it used to have an acutal number, and the password feild is obviously cenored *****.

How can I change the username and password? IBM's documentation wants me to do it from my PC, but I am just learning the basics so I have no idea where to even start.

Is it possible to change it from inside of the DB2 cloud interface?

Also, IBM itself only give you tech support if you upgrade to a real plan, so thats out of the question.

This is the error I get when I try to connect:

```
Unable to connect:  [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30082N  Security processing failed with reason "24" ("USERNAME AND/OR PASSWORD INVALID").  SQLSTATE=08001 SQLCODE=-30082
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a perfect case of mental-gridlock.

It is in the main dashboard, before you actually load into your DB2 cloud!

1. go to : cloud.idb.com/resources
2. select the service, in this case DB2
3. go to service credentials and WA LA!